# EPS to pdf conversion

Tags: eps, epstopdf

I am getting problems while updating the eps files. Can anyone help me how to use this package. I used inkscape software to draw the image and saved it in .eps format. Then i used epstopdf package in my latex script  then using includegraphics i gave the file name, but i am not getting proper output, and there is no error message also. Can anyone help how to use this command. Is that i have to use some more packages? or is that there is any other way to save eps files from inkscape? 
Please help...

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oldfontcommands]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx} % to recognise the written description of si-units and   make the acronym. 
\sisetup{%
inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
per-mode=symbol
 }

\usepackage{nomencl} 

 \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
 \usepackage{import}
  \usepackage{gensymb} 
  \usepackage{textcomp}

  % ********* Font definition *************
  \usepackage{t1enc} % as usual
  \usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc} % as usual
   \usepackage{times}
   \usepackage{epstopdf}
   \usepackage{nameref}

  %********For high quality figure (e.g: Matlab figures in latex )**********
  %\usepackage{tikz} 
  \usepackage{tikz-cd}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{epstopdf} % converts .eps image files to .pdf on the fly
  %\usepackage{xelatex} % converts all the image formats to .pdf on the fly
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}
  %\usepackage{tikzpicture}
 \usepackage{supertabular}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{footnote}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
 \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
 %\usepackage{ucs}
 %\usepackage{subfigure}
 %\usepackage{subfiles}




 \begin{document}


 \begin{figure}[!h]
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=6cm]{thick}
 \caption{Thick walled pipe}\label{fig:Thick walled pipe}
  \end{center}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

output of the image :

[image]

Comment: Please add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question. This makes it easier to understand and answer.

Comment: @Benjamin i have added a minimal working problem.

Comment: The example is not really minimal. Try removing everything above `\begin{document}`, except for the `\documentclass`, and compile with pdflatex (which automatically uses epstopdf). Does the problem persist? If it is solved, then add the lines back one by one to see if the problem returns.

Comment: probably not relevant: you have `\usepackage{epstopdf}` twice.  the image looks very like what would be expected with a `draft` option active, but i don't see where that has been indicated.

Comment: If I remove the two \usepackage{epstopdf} lines (not needed in recent versions of pdftex!---file.eps gets converted to file-eps-converted-to.pdf and that is automatically included) and also the \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps} line everything just works for me.

Comment: @HerbSchulz U r right, i tried doing the same, and now it is compiling correctly. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if `tikz-cd` loads a `graphic` package with the draft option if none is loaded. To have the correct output you have to load the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package before `epstopdf`.

A (more) minimal working example is:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=6cm]{thick}

\end{document}
```

You will notice that if you comment out `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` compiling results in several errors and no graphic is shown.